# Gnu/Linux (Bash) Bulk Command for Multiple Files

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

I am looking for a solution to run a command for multiple files at one.

Example for 1 file only:

```
dot -Tpng dummy.dot.modulename -o dummy.dot.modulename.png
```

Now example for all "*.dot*" (PSEUDO COMMAND)

```
dot -Tpng $(find . -name "*.dot*") -o $(find . -name "*.dot*").png
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Isn't that what `xargs` was built for?

Comment: all xarg does is generate a space separated argument list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the *.dot file globbing pattern

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for dotfile in *.dot
do
  # Create the png file name by removing the trailing .dot
  # and replacing it with .png
  pngfile="${dotfile%.dot}.png"
  dot -Tpng "$dotfile" -o "$pngfile"
done
```

Rather than loop over a filename globbing expansion. You can have `find` execute a command/script like this:

```sh
find . -name '*.dot' \
  -execdir sh 'for f; do dot -Tpng "$f" -o "${f%.dot}.png" ;done' {} \;
```

Comment: @oguzismail if not trimming the file name and globbing `*.dot*`, the script/commands can not be re-run (eg: if interrupted), or it will run over the png files and fail.